# CUDA large input arrays

Tags: c++, arrays, cuda, integer-overflow

I am new to CUDA, I have been working on a "Reduce algorithm".

The algorithm works for any array size less than 1<<24.

When I use arrays of size 1<<25 the program returns 0 in "total sum" which is wrong. The sum should me 2^25

**EDIT** cuda-memcheck compiled_code

```
========= CUDA-MEMCHECK
@@STARTING@@ 
========= Program hit cudaErrorInvalidValue (error 11) due to "invalid argument" on CUDA API call to cudaLaunch. 
=========     Saved host backtrace up to driver entry point at error
=========     Host Frame:/usr/lib64/libcuda.so.1 [0x2f2d83]
=========     Host Frame:test [0x3b37e]
=========     Host Frame:test [0x2b71]
=========     Host Frame:test [0x2a18]
=========     Host Frame:test [0x2a4c]
=========     Host Frame:test [0x2600]
=========     Host Frame:test [0x2904]
=========     Host Frame:/lib64/libc.so.6 (__libc_start_main + 0xfd) [0x1ed5d]
=========     Host Frame:test [0x23e9]
=========
```

My setup is:

- List item
- Nvidia Tesla K40
- CUDA 6.5
- Scientific Linux release 6.4 (Carbon)

The program consists of a kernel, a kernel wrapper and a main to execute the kernel wrapper.

```
/* -------- KERNEL -------- */
__global__ void reduce_kernel(int * d_out, int * d_in, int size)
{
  // position and threadId
  int pos = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
  int tid = threadIdx.x;

  // do reduction in global memory
  for (unsigned int s = blockDim.x / 2; s>0; s>>=1)
  {
    if (tid < s)
    {
      if (pos+s < size) // Handling out of bounds
      {
        d_in[pos] = d_in[pos] + d_in[pos+s];
      }
    }
    __syncthreads();
  }

  // only thread 0 writes result, as thread
  if ((tid==0) && (pos < size))
  {
    d_out[blockIdx.x] = d_in[pos];
  }
}
```

Here is the Kernel wrapper

```
/* -------- KERNEL WRAPPER -------- */
void reduce(int * d_out, int * d_in, int size, int num_threads)
{
  // setting up blocks and intermediate result holder

  int num_blocks;
  if(((size) % num_threads))
    {
      num_blocks = ((size) / num_threads) + 1;    
    }
    else
    {
      num_blocks = (size) / num_threads;
    }
  int * d_intermediate;
  cudaMalloc(&d_intermediate, sizeof(int)*num_blocks);
  cudaMemset(d_intermediate, 0, sizeof(int)*num_blocks);
  int prev_num_blocks;
  int i = 1;
  int size_rest = 0;
  // recursively solving, will run approximately log base num_threads times.
  do
  {
    printf("Round:%.d\n", i);
    printf("NumBlocks:%.d\n", num_blocks);
    printf("NumThreads:%.d\n", num_threads);
    printf("size of array:%.d\n", size);
    i++;
    reduce_kernel<<<num_blocks, num_threads>>>(d_intermediate, d_in, size);
    size_rest = size % num_threads;
    size = size / num_threads + size_rest;

    // updating input to intermediate
    cudaMemcpy(d_in, d_intermediate, sizeof(int)*num_blocks, cudaMemcpyDeviceToDevice);

    // Updating num_blocks to reflect how many blocks we now want to compute on
    prev_num_blocks = num_blocks;
    if(size % num_threads)
    {
      num_blocks = size / num_threads + 1;      
    }
    else
    {
      num_blocks = size / num_threads;
    }
    // updating intermediate
    cudaFree(d_intermediate);
    cudaMalloc(&d_intermediate, sizeof(int)*num_blocks);
  }
  while(size > num_threads); // if it is too small, compute rest.

  // computing rest
  reduce_kernel<<<1, size>>>(d_out, d_in, prev_num_blocks);
}
```

Here is the main:

```
/* -------- MAIN -------- */
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  printf("@@STARTING@@ \n");
  // Setting num_threads
  int num_threads = 512;
  // Making non-bogus data and setting it on the GPU
  const int size = 1<<24;
  const int size_out = 1;
  int * d_in;
  int * d_out;
  cudaMalloc(&d_in, sizeof(int)*size);
  cudaMalloc(&d_out, sizeof(int)*size_out);

  int * h_in = (int *)malloc(size*sizeof(int));
  for (int i = 0; i <  size; i++) h_in[i] = 1;
  cudaMemcpy(d_in, h_in, sizeof(int)*size, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

  // Running kernel wrapper
  reduce(d_out, d_in, size, num_threads);
  int result;
  cudaMemcpy(&result, d_out, sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
  printf("\nFINAL SUM IS: %d\n", result);
}
```

Comment: And what is the question?

Comment: I don't see any error  checking in your code anywhere. Are you sure that there are not any errors occurring when the code is run at large sizes?

Comment: @Angew The result should be 2^25

Comment: @talonmies would that be wrapping all of the cuda functions with checkCudaErrors ??

Comment: What debugging have you done so far? nSight? Or at least copying the data back to the CPU after each iteration and examining it? Stepping at least through the CPU code and verifying all is as you expect? Please tel us how far you've gotten. And if you haven't done any of this, go back and do it.

Comment: >>nvcc -o test my_reduce.cu
>>./test

Comment: That would the correct way to check for API errors at runtime. Alternatively, use cuda-memcheck. I have run your code with 2^28 entries and it reports the correct answer, which makes me believe you are hitting a runtime limit, like the Windows WDDM TDR limit or similar

Comment: @talonmies I have updated with memcheck in the OP, I am running on a Scientific Linux release 6.4 (Carbon)

Comment: You are compiling your code for an (incorrect, default) architecture that only supports 1D grids of 65535 blocks. At 2^25 points, you exceed the grid size limit and the first reduction kernel aborts with invalid launch arguments. Error checking would have told you this immediately and saved everyone a lot of time...

Comment: Thank you @talonmies, I will now use the cuda-memchecker on my compiled code before turning to SO :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This method of compiling your code:

```
nvcc -o my_reduce my_reduce.cu
```

[builds for a compute architecture](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-compiler-driver-nvcc/index.html#nvcc-examples) of cc2.0 on CUDA 6.5

That architecture is [limited to 65535 blocks](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#features-and-technical-specifications__technical-specifications-per-compute-capability) (in the x-dimension, which is the only dimension you are using) in the grid.

at a `size` of `1<<24`, with a `num_threads=512`, the number of blocks launched is:

```
  num_blocks = (size) / num_threads;
```

which is 1<<24/512 or  31250 blocks

at some number slightly above 1<<25 you will exceed the block limit of a cc2.0 device.

To fix this, compile with

```
nvcc -o -arch=sm_35 my_reduce my_reduce.cu
```

which is the [correct compile architecture (i.e. compute capability)](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-gpus) for your K40, and will raise the block limit to 2^31-1

And please use [proper cuda error checking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14038589/what-is-the-canonical-way-to-check-for-errors-using-the-cuda-runtime-api) any time you are having trouble with a CUDA code, *before* asking for help here.  Even if you don't understand the error results, it will likely help those who are trying to help you.

Comment: Yet again, thanks Robert! I will keep that in mind :)